# Matrix associated to $A(u)=u'''-3u''$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

How do i find the matrix associated to:

$A(u)=u'''-3u''$

with the basis:

- $\{e^t, e^{-t}\}$ for the domain
- $\{\sinh(t), \cosh(t)\}$ for the image

EDIT:

This is what i did so far:

1. Plug the components of the domain's basis into $A(u)$:
   $A(e^t)=e^t-3e^t=-2e^t$ **and** $A(e^{-t})=-e^{-t}-3e^{-t}=-4e^{-t}$
2. Try to write the previous results as a linear combination of the image  basis:
   $-2e^t=k_1\sinh(t)+k_2\cosh(t)$ **and** $-4e^{-t}=k_3\sinh(t)+k_4\cosh(t)$

Here is where i failed to go on but thanks to the suggestion of @Cameron Buie i think i worked it out:

$-2e^t=k_1\sinh(t)+k_2\cosh(t)=k_1(e^t/2-e^{-t}/2)+k_2(e^t/2+e^{-t}/2)$ **which is true for** $k_1=k_2=-2$
$-4e^t=k_3\sinh(t)+k_4\cosh(t)=k_3(e^t/2-e^{-t}/2)+k_4(e^t/2+e^{-t}/2)$ **which is true for** $k_3=4, k_4=-4$

So i think the matrix should be:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 4 \\
-2 & -4 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Recall/note that $$\cosh(t)=\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}2$$ and $$\sinh(t)=\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}2.$$

Now, what is $A(e^t)$ in terms of $\cosh(t)$ and $\sinh(t)$? What about $A(e^{-t})$? What can you conclude from this?

Comment: This is hardly a hint, but it's also hardly a question, so I suppose it is fitting!

Comment: @infinitylord can you please tell me what is wrong with my question so i can fix it? I wrote it in the same way it was asked on a test of my linear algebra course

Comment: @infinitylord: No? Starting from my hint, it takes only four steps to find the matrix.

Comment: @censacrof: That is precisely the problem, actually. On this website, you are expected to provide your attempt at the problem and explain where you became confused.

Comment: @CameronBuie: Yes, I agree with that statement entirely. My point is more that I would be surprised if the OP didn't already know those identities. That is how $\sinh(x), \cosh(x)$ are typically introduced. My guess would be that he is having problems elsewhere.

Comment: @Censacrof: The issue (as I see it) with your question is that you've shown no effort on your part. This is a problem for several reasons. First of all, it gives other users no idea of your experience level with the subject, so they'd have to guess at what you're missing. Second, since they have to guess, it's entirely possible that they'd give you more credit than you deserve on that front, and end up having to do a great deal more explaining than they expected. Third, showing none of your work comes off to many users as laziness, which is returned in kind by said many users. (continued)

Comment: @Censacrof: Fourth, it could well be that the other users won't give you enough credit, and waste both your and their time explaining things to you that you already know. Again, this discourages expending much effort on answering your question.

Comment: ok i will keep that in mind and edit my question. thanks for the advices

Comment: @infinitylord: Hopefully, the current hint is more to your liking.

Comment: @Censacrof: (+1) Nicely done! I'm glad my hint filled in the gap for you. If you feel that my answer helped you to get you to the solution, feel free to upvote it (hit the "up" arrow). If you feel that my answer got you to the solution on its own, feel free to "accept" it, as well (hit the "check" mark). The latter will let other users know that the question has been answered to your satisfaction, so that (1) nobody will waste their time composing another answer and (2) people with a similar question can more easily find the answer. Welcome to Math.SE!

Comment: Of course, @CameronBuie. I really thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Censacrof: You're very welcome!